# Why does Gandalf seem so fearless in the Siege of Minas Tirith?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium

When the battle began everyone was shrieking and screaming, soldiers looked scared, but when Gandalf rallied them they followed and fought against the Orc armies.

Gandalf seemed so confident and not scared or shaken at all. Why is this?

Comment: An interesting question. It's one thing, to display personal bravery; it's quite another, to lead an army of soldiers to battle against an apparently much stronger enemy. Gandalf seemed to have done both.

Comment: Um, because he is immortal? What is there to be afraid of?

Comment: A lot of things Mark Adler

Comment: @Mark Adler He might not have to fear old age, but I'm fairly certain an orc scimitar in his guts would kill him just as easily as any of the Minas Tirith defenders.

Comment: @MarkAdler: More than fearing for his own personal safety, Gandalf is likely to fear **failure**. If Gandalf's plans fail, Sauron enslaves everybody, forever. Gandalf is notable for his compassion, so this would worry him.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

## For a Combination of Reasons

There are many reasons why Gandalf appears so brave during the battle, some obvious, others less so.

### Gandalf is a hero

In almost every adventure story ever written, the hero is brave and steadfast in the face of mortal danger (or at least appears to be). That's what heroes do.

The story contrasts Gandalf's bravery with the despair felt by Denethor, who gives up hope, abandons his responsibilities, and prepares to commit suicide (and take his injured son Faramir with him). That's why Gandalf is a hero, and Denethor is (at best) a tragic victim.

### He is a brave individual

Throughout his earlier appearances in *The Hobbit* and *The Lord of the Rings*, Gandalf's outstanding characteristics include courage and resourcefulness. Even for a hero, he is not easy to frighten.

An example is Gandalf's stand against the Balrog in Moria -- he knows it is extremely dangerous and may kill him, but he still stays behind and fights to give his companions a chance to escape.

### He possesses one of the Three Rings

Gandalf is the keeper of Narya, the Ring of Fire, which is one of the three Elf-Rings, and said to give strength and courage to those who possess it.

### He has already died once

He (effectively) died fighting the Balrog in Moria, but was sent back to complete his task. This might give one a different perspective on personal danger.

### He is an angel

Tolkien's notes in *The Silmarillion* and *Unfinished Tales* make it clear that Gandalf is one of the immortal race of beings known as the Maiar (singular Maia), sent to Middle Earth to oppose Sauron. Gandalf is **not human**, and has much greater wisdom and power than any human being.

### He may have been scared, but not shown it

In the film *Return of the King*, Gandalf tells Pippin before the battle that he has "not yet been tested" against the Witch-King of Angmar (the chief Ringwraith). At this time, Gandalf definitely sounds worried.

In a scene during the battle (which appears in the extended DVD editions), Gandalf confronts the Witch-King, who breaks Gandalf's staff and looks as though he may be able to defeat him. At this point, Gandalf does look afraid. Fortunately for him, the Riders of Rohan arrive at this moment and the Witch-King flies off to deal with them.

## Conclusion

Of all people in Middle-Earth at that time, Gandalf was one of the *most* capable of displaying courage and leadership to oppose Sauron's attack on Minas Tirith. Through a combination of good luck, good planning, and fate/destiny, he was in the right place at the right time to lead the defence and save the city.

Comment: I knew everything but the elvenring part. Thanks a lot. Moreover, in which content may I find these details ?

Comment: Gandalf's elven ring is mentioned in the book of *Return of the King*.

Comment: Oo i'll read it back then ;)

Comment: @LudovicZenohateLagouardette https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_Rings#Narya too

Comment: Let's not forget he's also thousands of years old. After that kind of while you've probably seen enough craziness to keep your cool most of the time.

Comment: I particularly like the explanation that Gandalf was scared but refused to show it: after Denethor gives up, he leads the effort to rally the people of Minas Tirith to stand firm against their attackers. Given that he's wielding Narya, a ring of power that Cirdan described as "... the Ring of Fire, and with it you may rekindle hearts in a world that grows chill" probably helped with this.